# Linked Server disconnects on desktop logoff

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Having a really odd issue that I am banging my head against.

SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server R2 setting up a linked server using a 3rd party ODBC driver.

Created the system DSN for the third party connection on the sql server, created the linked server using:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'NS_PROD', @srvproduct=N'NS', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'NS_PROD', @location=N'NS', @provstr=N'SDSN=xxx;HST=xxx;PRT=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx', @catalog=N'Administrator'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'NS_PROD',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'xxx',@rmtpassword='xxx'
```

Logged in to local desktop, fired up SSMS, tested linked server successfully.

After logging out of the desktop of the SQL Server, within 10 minutes, linked server starts timing out from SSMS.

Logging back into the SQL Server desktop restores the connection to the linked server.

Is it losing the ability to access the system DSN if there is no user desktop? This make no sense to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network firewall caused the issue.